# Subscribe returning Void instead of AnyCancelable

Tags: swift, combine

I currently have a publisher with the type of `AnyPublisher<[MyClass], Error>` to which I'm attempting to attach a subscriber and capture the resulting `AnyCancelable`. Xcode's autocomplete says I should be able to do this, but when the code is actually entered, I encounter a compiler error saying that the returned type isn't `AnyCancelable`, but `()`

Here's an example of my code:

```
let networkController = NetworkController()
let viewState = MyViewState()

let publisher: AnyPublisher<[MyClass], Error> = networkController.createPublisher()
let cancelable: AnyCancellable = publisher.subscribe(viewState)
Cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type 'AnyCancellable'
```

My goal here is to wrap an existing async function, which could be called numerous times, in the Combine Framework, so that I can have a nice way of having the request get canceled when it's reassigned, like so:

```
... self.cancelable = cancelable
```

Comment: Is `MyViewState` a class?

Comment: Oops, yes it is. Forgot the init in the example.

Answer (score 2):

`AnyPublisher` has **two** `subscribe` methods for attaching a `Subscriber` to a `Publisher`. It inherits both from the `Publisher` protocol. Here they are:

```
func subscribe<S>(_ subscriber: S)
    where S : Subscriber, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Input

func subscribe<S>(_ subject: S) -> AnyCancellable
    where S : Subject, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Output
```

So, I guess your `MyViewState` type doesn’t conform to the `Subject` protocol. Therefore you can’t use the version of `subscribe` that returns `AnyCancellable`.

`Subject` is sub-protocol of `Publisher` that exposes `send` methods for injecting values which the `Subject` then publishes. Do you want your `MyViewState` class to be a `Publisher`? I suspect not.

What you probably want to do instead is change your `MyViewState` type to not even conform to `Subscriber`. Instead, use `AnyPublisher`’s `sink` method (also inherited from `Publisher`) to connect the publisher to your `viewState`. The `sink` method returns a `Sink` object that conforms to `Cancellable`:

```
func sink(
    receiveCompletion: ((Subscribers.Completion<Failure>) -> Void)? = nil,
    receiveValue: @escaping ((Output) -> Void))
    -> Subscribers.Sink<Output, Failure>
```

You can wrap the returned `Cancellable` in `AnyCancellable` if needed. Thus:

```
let can = publisher.sink(
    receiveCompletion: { viewModel.receive(completion: $0) },
    receiveValue: { viewModel.receive($0) })
let anyCan = AnyCancellable(can)
```